# Android Studio does not compile android library (AAR) with C ++ with implementation in gradle

Tags: android, c++, aar

to see if someone can give me a light with a problem in Android Studio (v 3.3.1).

It turns out that I have two modules, a normal APP and an Android Library (AAR), the latter has implementations in C ++ with NDK. (only the hello world example in c ++, there is no more code)

Problem: If I compile the AAR independently it is generated without problems with its C ++ files and all good .. But if I add it locally to the APP with "implementation" in gradle to test it while developing, then the AAR loses all reference to the C ++ files and the folder "cpp" is "closed" giving compilation error for lack of those files, I also notice that the compilation modes disappear what is happening?

Question: Has anyone managed to create a project with an app and an AAR module that implements C ++?

[image: screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Yes I *have*. Question *answered*. If you would like to know why *yours* is not working,  **SHOW YOUR BUILD.GRADLE FILES AND ERROR LOGS** (as per usual). Also your whole directory structure may help (you need to put the right things in the right places). Try not to use images if it does not help, we like text (searchable).

Comment: 0 when the structure of the 'cpp' appears lost then that indicates the gradle sync aborted with errors; you'll have three gradle.build files: one in the project root, one in the app/ folder, and the third for the aar in the, say, myLibrary folder. without the build.gradle files and the error logs in front of us, how do you suggest we'd figure out what has happened... ;-) kindly provide those files for analysis.